# Prove that $p|a-1$ in LTE

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Prove that if the odd prime $p$ divides $a^b-1,$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then $p$ appears to the same power in the prime factorisation of $b(a^d-1),$ where $d=\gcd(b,p-1).$

So I want to use lifting the exponent. Now clearly $p\not\mid a.$
Now (say) we have $p|a-1$ then by LTE,

$$v_p((a^d)^{b/d}-1)= v_p(a^d-1)+v_p(b/d)= v_p(a^d-1)+v_p(b)$$ ( as $d<p-1<p$)

And $$ v_p(b(a^d-1))= v_p(a^d-1)+v_p(b)$$

So they have the same power.

So if we have $p|a-1$ we will be done. Any hints on how to show $p|a-1?$

Comment: In general $p$ won't always divide $a-1$. For instance $a=4$ and $b=2$ we could have easily ended up with either case of $p=3$ or $p=5$.

Comment: @SunainaPati FYI, there are few minor issues. First, where you state $d \lt p - 1 \lt p$, the first $\lt$ should be $\le$ instead. Second, the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function is not $v$ but it's $\nu$, i.e., the Greek letter of `\nu` (note you can also verify by checking the Wikipedia article). Finally, instead of the vertical bar of $|$, you should use `\mid` since it helps with things like spacing, e.g., instead of $p | a - 1$, you get $p \mid a - 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, but you only actually need to show that $p \mid a^d - 1$, not that $p \mid a - 1$ since that's not always necessarily true. To do this, using the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order), set

$$\operatorname{ord}_p(a) = c \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since it's given that $p \mid a^b - 1$, and $p \mid a^{p-1} - 1$ by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), then

$$c \mid b \; \land \; c \mid p - 1 \implies c \mid (\gcd(b, p - 1) = d) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means that

$$p \mid a^d - 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $d \le p - 1 \lt p$, this then allows using the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) to get what you've already shown in the question.

Comment: wow, I was close! Thanks a lot of answering :)! Learnt a lot!